# What is QScrollBar::add-line?

Tags: qt, scrollbar

From the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html),

> The ::add-line subcontrol can be used to style the button to add a
>   line. By default, the add-line subcontrol is placed in top right
>   corner of the Border rectangle of the widget. Depending on the
>   orientation the ::right-arrow or ::down-arrow. By default, the arrows
>   are placed in the center of the Contents rectangle of the add-line
>   subcontrol.

What's the mean of "style the button to add a line"? What's the appearance of a line? How is it shaped? What's the function of such a line?

AFAIK, a scroll-bar is consist of a background rectangle, two arrow buttons and a rectangle act as the handle:
[image: scroll-bar]

Comment: There is a link [Customizing QScrollBar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qscrollbar) at the end of doc. (you provided the link for). It shows an example for this (scrolling down a bit). Though, I'm not sure in which specific situations one wants to offer adding a line or a page. It may depend on the application... (May be, this is similar like in modern web browsers where you have such a special tab to add new pages. I just recently had a hard time in Qt to emulate this by a regular tab.) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff Thanks! But I still failed to understand what is a line or a page. I have 
 noticed the example, but it doesn't provide any screenshot.

Comment: Scroll bars [`QScrollbar`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollbar.html#details) offer a small step and a page step. The small (single) step can be done e.g. clicking the arrow buttons. The page step can be done clicking the pane around the slider (above, below or left, right). I believe add line addresses increasing the range by a small step where add page - increasing the range by a page step. I must admit that I think "add single step" would've been more consistent to stay in one unique terminology. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> the button to add a line

This is the button that **adds a line in your scroll-area** (in the direction of your scrollbar, horizontal or vertical), i.e. to scroll one line (down/right, the *sub-line control* will scroll one line up/left).

This is just the regular button with an arrow that you already identified on your screenshot. The default button and behaviour for scrollbars as we see them in most of GUIs.

This *one line* is actually called `single step` in the [QAbstractSlider](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#details) doc.

These stylesheet controls `QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal`, `QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal`, `QScrollBar::add-page:horizontal`, `QScrollBar:left-arrow:horizontal` etc allow to customize the look of these parts of the widget.

---

The other control `QScrollBar::add-page:` will allow you customize the widget area that scrolls not just one line but one page.
The size of a page can be defined by [`setPageStep(int)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#pageStep-prop) while the size of the *one line* can be defined by [`setSingleStep(int)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#singleStep-prop).

There is no button to add/sub one *page-step*. Instead you have to click in the empty space between the handle and the buttons to add/sub one line.

From what I tested (Qt5.10) this will be processed only if you also customize the `QScrollBar` as well. The example of the doc given by *Scheff* [Customizing QScrollBar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qscrollbar) shows a full usage of what you can customize on a `QScrollBar`.

Comment: *i.e. to scroll one line*, do you mean that by clicking an *add-line* button, the page is scrolled up or down for one line? Could you provide a screenshot of the add-line button, please?

Comment: @zwcloud This is the default button. The one you show in your screenshot. The `add-page` button is no longer used nowadays from what I see, you can see it on this old capture of Microsoft Word for example : http://content.gcflearnfree.org/topics/14/wn_scrollbar.gif